# Ajax Php Login form txt file

Tags: php, ajax, forms, authentication, passwords

I'm trying to setup a ajax login form with php verification if user/passw exist in txt file.

The form :

```
    <form class="form login" id="log_user">

    <input id="login__username" type="text" name="username" class="form__input" placeholder="Username" required>

    <input id="login__password" type="password" name="password" class="form__input" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Log In">

</form>
```

The javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#log_user").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST", 
        data:{
            username : $("#login__username").val(),
            password : $("#login__password").val()
            }, 
        url:"log_user.php",
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'Success'){
                alert('Login Passw correct');
                }
            else{
                alert(data);
                }
        },
         error: function(){
                alert('something went wrong');
        }
    });
    return false;
});});
```

The PHP :

```
    <?php

foreach(file('passwd.txt') as $line) {

    if(empty($line)) continue;

    $lineArray = explode(':', $line);
    $username = rtrim($lineArray[0]);
    $password = rtrim($lineArray[1]);

    if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){

        if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){ 
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            echo "Success";    
        }
        else{
            echo "Failed";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

the passwd.txt

```
myname:mypassw
myname2:mypassw2
```

each time i try I have a SuccessFailed or FailedFailed, don't understand why ?
A clue ?

Comment: Side note: Is there a reason in particular as to why you're using a text file for this and not a database? The former would make it a lot easier to manage than text files and safer.

Comment: For one thing, it looks to me like you're probably outputting before header. What does `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` throw back?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?  You're doing a `foreach`, so everything within that block (including the output commands) is going to run for each line in the file.

Comment: `if(empty($line)) continue;` - do you realize what you're doing here?

Comment: This is so so so so so so so so **_SO_** insecure.

Comment: thx guy for your replies and sorry if my code is horrible... I wasn't waiting for the magic @Funk Forty Niner, just out the office ;) I can't use MYSQL as it has to be very easy to setup and there is no critical data to protect... I get the point about the loop thing but I'm so new to php that I don't know how to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `foreach` loop. I'm assuming you have more than one username and password stored? If you enter a correct un and pw it echos success, but you've not told it to stop at that point, so the next entry runs which does not match the un and pw, so it echoes failure.

The solution here is to use a variable outside the `foreach` that, if the username and password are found, is toggled to a truthy value (in this case `TRUE`). After the `foreach`, we check the value of this variable and `echo` the appropriate response:

```
$success = FALSE;
foreach(file('passwd.txt') as $line) {

    if(empty($line)) continue;

    $lineArray = explode(':', $line);
    $username = rtrim($lineArray[0]);
    $password = rtrim($lineArray[1]);

    if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){

        if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){ 
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            $success = TRUE;
            break; // stop looping through text file.
        }
    }
}
echo $success ? 'Success' : 'Failed';
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Richard, I understand the bug, but unfortunately it doesn't work with the first usern/passwd of the list ? I made a barebone here : https://www.360images.fr/login_barebone/